# React use setState to update nested object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to update a nested object in React using `setState`, which is in a function that is called from a form `onChange` event. The code below works the first time it is called, but after that I get an error `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')`. What am I doing wrong?

```
const initialState = {
    email: { value: "", hasError: true, error: "" },
    password: { value: "", hasError: true, error: "" }
}

const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

function handleChange(event) {
    setState(state[event.target.name].value = event.target.value);
}
```

Comment: State is immutable, you need to copy the object first. See this question: [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `setState` like that. You need to get the previous value from `setState`. There is a prev argument in `setState` that allows you to pass the previous values into the function. You can use the spread operator (https://www.w3schools.com/REACT/react_es6_spread.asp) to keep all untouched values the same. For instance:

```
const initialState = {
  email: { value: "", hasError: true, error: "" },
  password: { value: "", hasError: true, error: "" }
}

const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

function handleChange(event) {
  setState(prev => ({
    ...prev,
    email: {
      value: "value",
      hasError: false,
      error: ""
    }
  }));
}
```

Also - You can just check if there's an error by evaluating the `error` property. Something like `!!state?.email?.error` so you don't need the extra boolean in there (obviously if there's an error string, then it means there's an error). Just clear the error string on reset and it'll be false again.

Info on setState: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-does-setstate-do